# How to use utf-8 characters in a comment in Python source code?

Tags: python, utf-8, comments

I think that I understand how to create a string that encodes a UTF-8 characters.  But, I'm trying to do something a bit different.  Is it possible to use UTF-8 characters in a comment in Python source code?  And, are there any Python IDEs or source code editors that will recognize the UTF-8 sequences and display the characters correctly?

Comment: Yes, just write some Unicode characters in your editor, save, and run it.

Comment: @Ry- I'm vaguely disappointed that I can't write  = **2.

Comment: See the [python unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) docs, [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) and and [PEP 3120](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) making utf-8 the default encoding for python 3.x. If your editor / ide doesn't support unicode by now, update your tool chain!

Comment: I've tested several code editors, including MS Visual Studio 2015.  So far, nothing that I've tried will recognize the sequence U+00B0 as a degree sign.

Comment: Do you mean the literal text “U+00B0”? Because you need to write “°”, not “U+00B0”. On Windows, [there are a few ways to get that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input), e.g. Alt+0176.

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 can certainly use UTF-8 files as source code, but it will try to use the default ANSI encoding if you just type a degree sign in source code and your ANSI encoding encodes the character (varies by localized Windows version).  Use a tool like Notepad++ to save the source as UTF-8 and VS2015 still detects and reads the file correctly.

The below file was created in Notepad++ and saved as Encoding, UTF-8:

```
print('\u00b0')  # This is a °.
print('°°°°')    # So are these.
```

It displays correctly loaded in VS2015 as well.

Comment: When I put a degree symbol into a print statement, I get the following error when I attempt to run the code: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 25: invalid start byte

Comment: You have to save the file as utf8, or declare the encoding you did use at the top of the Python script with `#coding: ansi` for example.  Python 3 assumes utf8 otherwise.